# format conversion

Tags: c, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, yuv, rgba

In OpenGL ES 2.0 after reading the framebuffer and converting it to RGBA frames. I want to convert it to YUV format.

I tried using this [table](http://www.fourcc.org/fccyvrgb.php). Which ignore alpha component. When i do that and see the YUV frame generated its distorted.

Can anyone help me please

```
yuvdata[i * j *1]= (0.257)*memory[i*j*1] + (0.504)*memory[i*j*2]+(0.098)*memory[i*j*3]+16;
yuvdata[i * j *3]= (0.439)*memory[i*j*1] - (0.368)*memory[i*j*2] -(0.071)*memory[i*j*3]+128;
yuvdata[i * j *2]= -(0.148)*memory[i*j*1] - (0.291)*memory[i*j*2] +(0.439)*memory[i*j*3]+128;
```

`

Normalization did not help
memory store rgba
and yuv is free space to store yuv

i used rgb to yuv conversion ignoring alpha component

Friends this problem is resolved. This article is awesome[yuv2rgb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV#Converting_between_Y.27UV_and_RGB). Thanks to Viktor Latypov and Mārtiņš Možeiko

Comment: There are YUV420p, YUV411, YUV422 and YUV444. The first three must be converted to YUV444 before applying the matrix. What is the exact YUV format you want to use ?

Comment: @ViktorLatypov: How do i convert YUV420p YUV411 and YUv422 to YUV 444? 

I am just taking RGB and converting using the above formula. which must give a consistant YUV format. Please correct me if i am wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"YUV" is not a complete format.

From [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV) you can get the conversions of YUV411,YUV422,YUV420p to YUV444. Combine the inverse of these transforms with your RGB conversion and you'll get the result.

The thing you are missing: one RGB triple may produce a number (not one) of YUV components this way.

1. YUV444    3 bytes per pixel
2. YUV422    4 bytes per 2 pixels
3. YUV411    6 bytes per 4 pixels
4. YUV420p   6 bytes per 4 pixels, reordered

First, YUV422

Y'UV422 to RGB888 conversion

Input: Read 4 bytes of Y'UV (u, y1, v, y2 )

Output: Writes 6 bytes of RGB (R, G, B, R, G, B)

Then YUV4111

Y'UV411 to RGB888 conversion

Input: Read 6 bytes of Y'UV

Output: Writes 12 bytes of RGB

```
// Extract YUV components
u  = yuv[0];
y1 = yuv[1];
y2 = yuv[2];
v  = yuv[3];
y3 = yuv[4];
y4 = yuv[5];
rgb1 = Y'UV444toRGB888(y1, u, v);
rgb2 = Y'UV444toRGB888(y2, u, v);
rgb3 = Y'UV444toRGB888(y3, u, v);
rgb4 = Y'UV444toRGB888(y4, u, v);
```

Similar with 420p, but the YUV values are distributed over the rectangle there - see the Wikipedia's diagram and image for that.

Basically, you should fetch 4 RGB pixels, convert each one of them to YUV (using your hopefully valid 444 converter) and then store the YUV[4] array in a tricky way shown at the wikipedia.

Comment: In my case i took RGB components and converted to  YUV444. Now i am converting to YUV 420. This answer helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are accessing memory array correctly right? Shouldn't it be something like this:

```
R=memory[(i*width + j)*4+0]
G=memory[(i*width + j)*4+1]
B=memory[(i*width + j)*4+3]
```

or swap 0 with 3, if you have BGRA.

Comment: @Martin I changed the memory which i access to to +0 +1 +3 but the result is same..

Comment: It is not possible that the result is the same!

Comment: @Martins Thank you. I was wrong. :) after doing it my problem was with the datatype. I resolved it. 
Thank you once again